# Excel - Can you use both Relative R1C1 Reference Notation and A1 Reference Notation in the Same Excel File?

Tags: microsoft-excel

The question is straight forward. Can I use both Relative **R1C1 Reference** Notation and **A1 Reference** Notation in the Same Excel File?

I know that I can change between A1 and R1C1 Reference Style from `Excel > Options > Formulas`. But I would like to explore a possibility of using both of them in the same file? [Consequently, I want to keep the original A1 style Referencing for Formula but want to use Relative R1C1 style referencing as per need basis].

[image: R1C1 and A1 reference notation styles]

Thank you.

Comment: In your screenshot example it may be for `Total`: `=INDIRECT("R[-4]C",)+INDIRECT("R[-3]C",)` with relative references.

Comment: @MGonet, you are right, I did make a mistake and after taking the screenshot, I realized it. Great observation.

Answer (score 1):

You can *use* them in the same file.

But you must switch between one and another. You can't type an A1 formula, then type an R1C1 formula without first switching the reference style.

When you switch, all formulas are converted to the style to which you have switched.

So to directly answer your question: no.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `A1` style in your sheet, you can only use the `R1C1` style in 4 places at a time (at least I don't know more):

1. In formulas with the `INDIRECT` function (as text) with the second argument `FALSE`,
2. In `HYPERLINK` formulas where the address is provided as text,
3. In the `Name Box`,
4. In `VBA`.

Comment: can you please give an example of indirect function with R1C1 method, if possible? Thank you.

Comment: For example: `=INDIRECT("R2C4",)` is equivalent to `=INDIRECT("D2")`. You can also use relative references, their meaning depends in which cell you use a formula.

Comment: To be more explicit, the format is `=INDIRECT(ref_text, [a1])` where `ref_text` is the range reference *as a string* and `[a1]` is an optional true / false parameter indicating if the string is in the A1 format (true) or R1C1 (false). See the [Microsoft support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) for more details.

Comment: +1. You can do this, but it's not recommended as INDIRECT is a volatile function, which will cause recalculation of the entire workbook when anything changes.

Comment: A volatile function does not cause recalculation of the whole workbook. The formula containing a volatile function is recalculated, and may trigger downstream calculations in the workbook to recalculate. IIRC the triggering of dependent cells to recalculate will only happen if the *value* in the volatile cell actually changes when recalculated. Eg NOW vs TODAY, or RAND vs INDIRECT